# Closing popped out utility bar from cross button

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, utility-bar, popup-window

I have a utility bar which is having features to search for articles.
I am using it to pop out from the bar to and independent utility window, when I use the pop-in button to take it back into the utility bar then everything working fine.
**The issue here is:** When I use the cross button to close the utility window then it is not getting back to utility bar and it's not in working state.

Here is the GIF, showing the issue.
http://g.recordit.co/Sq6qvMGqci.gif